# Bound of a scaled random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $S$ be a Markov Chain on the non-negative integers such that $S_0 = s_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and
$S_{k+1} = S_k +1$ with probability $p$ and $S_{k+1} = S_k -1$ with probability $1-p$.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define
$$\bar{S}_n(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}S_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}$$

Fix $t \geq 0$. I want to determine $\sup_n |\bar{S}_n(t)|$. I am guessing an additional condition is needed for this supremum to be finite.

So far, I have

\begin{align*}
|\bar{S}_n(t)| &= \left| \frac{S_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}} \right|\\
&\leq \frac{|s_0| + \lfloor nt\rfloor}{\sqrt{n}}\\
&\leq |\bar{S}_n(0)|+ \frac{nt}{\sqrt{n}} = |\bar{S}_n(0)| + \sqrt{n}t
\end{align*}

Can we improve this upper bound that would be independent of $n$? Or what additional condition can we have?

Comment: Quite messy, to be honest. It seems that $s_0$ plays no part in the calculation, and curiously the result does not depend on it either. Strange, I would expect the result to depend on the initial position. The second equality should be an inequality, and you should add $s_0$, but otherwise, in essence, the calculation is correct. A more important question is what is the purpose of this? You gave the most trivial deterministic upper bound for a random variable, loosing randomness completely. What do you need this for?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. will fix that. I wrote out the trivial part to emphasize that without any additional condition, I do not have anything. I do want a finite upper bound. This is just a small portion of a huge proof for a theorem I want to prove.

Comment: As I said, what you wrote is correct, but this is an absolutely trivial estimation. It is hard to imagine that it is useful for anything. But in any case, good luck for the proof.